# Is there a way to get batches with continuous examples in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a dataset with 10,000+ examples and using Dataloader, I create batches of size 50. I'm trying to find a way to have batch 1 start at example 1 and end at example 50 then have batch 2 start at example 2 and end at example 51 and so on.

This is a snip of where I use DataLoader:

```py
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size=batch_size, drop_last=True, shuffle=False)

    for epoch in range(num_epochs): 
        totalEpochs += 1

        for X, y in train_loader:

            train = X.view(-1, 1, X.shape[1]).float()
```

Comment: batches are used to push more traininig sets to the NN at once, there is literally no reason to do what you want to do, hence there is no way of doing it without writing a custom `DataLoader`. If the data you are pushing in the net is interdependent and therefore you want that sliding window approach your network/training data is structured incorrectly.

You could technically use the `DataLoader` with batch size 1 and keep a list of samples of length 50, always `pop`ing the first and concatenating your batch manually, but that makes no sense logically and "performancely".

Comment: The reason for wanting to do this is because I wanted to see if it would help training my RNN by applying the data in this sliding window approach. If you think the DataLoader is the wrong way to go about this then I would look into another way to do it. What are your thoughts on doing this for a RNN.

Answer (score 0):

```
def timeseries_to_supervised(data, seq_length):
    x = []
    y = []

   for i in range(len(data)-seq_length-1):
       _x = data[i:(i+seq_length)]
       _y = data[i+seq_length]
       x.append(_x)
       y.append(_y)

   return np.array(x),np.array(y)



data = range(180)    
window_size = 30  # 60 mins

x,y = timeseries_to_supervised(data, window_size)

train_data = x[:90]
train_label = y[:90]
test_data = x[90:]
test_label = y[90:]  

trainX = Variable(torch.Tensor(np.array(train_data)))
trainY = Variable(torch.Tensor(np.array(train_label)))

testX = Variable(torch.Tensor(np.array(test_data)))
testY = Variable(torch.Tensor(np.array(test_label)))

batch = 24

from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader   

train_loader = (DataLoader(TimeSeriesDataSet(trainX, trainY), batch_size=batch,           shuffle=False))

test_loader = (DataLoader(TimeSeriesDataSet(testX, testY), batch_size=batch, shuffle=False))



for i, d in enumerate(train_loader):
   print(i, d[0].shape, d[1].shape)
   print (d) # d[0] - features , d[1] - labels
```

Results:
0 torch.Size([24, 30]) torch.Size([24])
[tensor([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12., 13.,
14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23., 24., 25., 26., 27.,
28., 29.],
[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12., 13., 14.,
15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23., 24., 25., 26., 27., 28.,
29., 30.],
[ 2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 15.,
16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23., 24., 25., 26., 27., 28., 29.,
30., 31.],
...
[23., 24., 25., 26., 27., 28., 29., 30., 31., 32., 33., 34., 35., 36.,
37., 38., 39., 40., 41., 42., 43., 44., 45., 46., 47., 48., 49., 50.,
51., 52.]]),
tensor([30., 31., 32., 33., 34., 35., 36., 37., 38., 39., 40., 41., 42., 43.,
44., 45., 46., 47., 48., 49., 50., 51., 52., 53.])]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).